# Stopping an actionscript animation

Tags: flash, loops, animation, actionscript

How do you stop an autoloop animation that is based on actionscript and not on movieclip?
I already tried adding a stop on the end frame but didn't work. I'm using actionscript 3.0 by the way.

```
init();
    function init():void {
        displayWidth = 785;
        displayHeight = 285;
        waitCount = 100;
        minWait = 10;
        maxWait = 130;
        count = waitCount - 1;
        flareList = new Particle3DList();
        sparkList = new Particle3DList();
        maxDragFactorFlare = 0.6;
        maxDragFactorSpark = 0.6;
        maxNumSparksAtNewFirework = 3000;
        gravity = 0.03;
        maxNumFlares = 90; 
        maxNumSparksPerFlare = 2; 
        topMargin = 6;
        displayHolder = new Sprite;
        displayHolder.x = 100;
        displayHolder.y = 0;
        sparkBitmapData = new BitmapData(displayWidth, displayHeight, true, 0x00000000);
        sparkBitmap = new Bitmap(sparkBitmapData);  
        var alphaToWhite:Number = 0.5;
        var alphaMult:Number = 1.6;
        var cmf:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter([1,0,0,alphaToWhite,0,                                                   0,1,0,alphaToWhite,0,                                                     0,0,1,alphaToWhite,0,                                                         0,0,0,alphaMult,0]);
        sparkBitmap.filters = [cmf];
        sky = new Sprite();
        starLayer = new Sprite();
        starLayer.x = 0;
        starLayer.y = 0;
        starLayer.blendMode = BlendMode.LIGHTEN;
        var k:int;
        var starGray:Number;
        var starY:Number;
        for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            starY = Math.random()*(displayHeight - 2);
        }
        var skyline:Sprite = new McSkyline() as Sprite;
        skyline.x = 1000;
        skyline.y = 1000;
        var frame:Shape = new Shape();
        frame.graphics.drawRect(0,0,displayWidth,displayHeight);
        frame.x = displayHolder.x;
        frame.y = displayHolder.y;
        this.addChild(displayHolder);
        displayHolder.addChild(sky);
        displayHolder.addChild(starLayer);
        displayHolder.addChild(sparkBitmap);
        displayHolder.addChild(skyline);
        this.addChild(frame);
        darken = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,0.87);
        blur = new BlurFilter(4,4,1);
        origin = new Point(0,0); //used in filters
        colorList = new <uint>[0x68ff04, 0xefe26d, 0xfc4e50, 0xfffae7, 0xffffff, 0xffc100,                  0xe02222,0xffa200,0xff0000,0x8aaafd,0x3473e5, 0xc157b7,0x9b3c8a, 0xf9dc98, 0xdc9c45, 0xee9338];
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
    }
    function onEnter(evt:Event):void {      
        count++;
        if ((count >= waitCount)&&(sparkList.numOnStage < maxNumSparksAtNewFirework)) {
```

randomizer

```
waitCount = minWait+Math.random()*(maxWait - minWait);
                fireworkColor = randomColor();
                count = 0;
                flareOriginX = 125 + Math.random()*300;
                flareOriginY = 90 + Math.random()*90;
                var i:int;
                var sizeFactor:Number = 0.1 + Math.random()*0.9;
                numFlares = (0.25+0.75*Math.random()*sizeFactor)*maxNumFlares;
                for (i = 0; i < numFlares; i++) {
                    var thisParticle:Particle3D = flareList.addParticle(flareOriginX, flareOriginY,0);
                    theta = 2*Math.random()*Math.PI;
                    phi = Math.acos(2*Math.random()-1);
                    mag = 8 + sizeFactor*sizeFactor*10;//sizeFactor*(60 + 3*Math.random());
                    thisParticle.vel.x = mag*Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta);
                    thisParticle.vel.y = mag*Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta);
                    thisParticle.vel.z = mag*Math.cos(phi);
                    thisParticle.airResistanceFactor = 0.015;
                    //envelope - this determines how long a flare will live.
                    thisParticle.envelopeTime1 = 45 + 60*Math.random();

                    thisParticle.color = fireworkColor;
                }
            }
            particle  = flareList.first;
            while (particle != null) {
                nextParticle = particle.next;
                dragFactor = particle.airResistanceFactor*Math.sqrt(particle.vel.x*particle.vel.x + particle.vel.y*particle.vel.y + particle.vel.z*particle.vel.z);
                if (dragFactor > maxDragFactorFlare) {
                    dragFactor = maxDragFactorFlare;
                }
                particle.vel.x += 0.05*(Math.random()*2 - 1);
                particle.vel.y += 0.05*(Math.random()*2 - 1) + gravity;
                particle.vel.z += 0.05*(Math.random()*2 - 1);
                particle.vel.x -= dragFactor*particle.vel.x;
                particle.vel.y -= dragFactor*particle.vel.y;
                particle.vel.z -= dragFactor*particle.vel.z;
                particle.pos.x += particle.vel.x;
                particle.pos.y += particle.vel.y;
                particle.pos.z += particle.vel.z;
                particle.age += 1;
                if (particle.age > particle.envelopeTime1) {
                    particle.dead = true;
                }
                if ((particle.dead)||(particle.pos.x > displayWidth) || (particle.pos.x < 0) || (particle.pos.y > displayHeight) || (particle.pos.y < -topMargin)) {
                    flareList.recycleParticle(particle);
                }       
                else {
                    numSparks = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxNumSparksPerFlare+1)*(1 - particle.age/particle.envelopeTime1));
                    for (i = 0; i < maxNumSparksPerFlare; i++) {
                        randDist = Math.random();
                        var thisSpark:Particle3D = sparkList.addParticle(particle.pos.x - randDist*particle.vel.x, particle.pos.y - randDist*particle.vel.y, 0, 0);
                        thisSpark.vel.x = 0.2*(Math.random()*2 - 1);
                        thisSpark.vel.y = 0.2*(Math.random()*2 - 1);
                        thisSpark.envelopeTime1 = 10+Math.random()*40;
                        thisSpark.envelopeTime2 = thisSpark.envelopeTime1 + 6 + Math.random()*6;
                        thisSpark.airResistanceFactor = 0.2;
                        thisSpark.color = particle.color;
                    }
                }

                particle = nextParticle;
            }
            sparkBitmapData.lock();
            //old particles will not be erased. Instead we will apply filters which more gradually fade out the particles.
            sparkBitmapData.colorTransform(sparkBitmapData.rect, darken);
            sparkBitmapData.applyFilter(sparkBitmapData, sparkBitmapData.rect, origin, blur);
            spark  = sparkList.first;
            while (spark != null) {
                nextSpark = spark.next;
                dragFactor = spark.airResistanceFactor*Math.sqrt(spark.vel.x*spark.vel.x + spark.vel.y*spark.vel.y);
                if (dragFactor > maxDragFactorSpark) {
                    dragFactor = maxDragFactorSpark;
                }
                spark.vel.x += 0.07*(Math.random()*2 - 1);
                spark.vel.y += 0.07*(Math.random()*2 - 1) + gravity;
                spark.vel.x -= dragFactor*spark.vel.x;
                spark.vel.y -= dragFactor*spark.vel.y;
                spark.pos.x += spark.vel.x;
                spark.pos.y += spark.vel.y;
                spark.age += 1;
                if (spark.age < spark.envelopeTime1) {
                    sparkAlpha = 255;
                }
                else if (spark.age < spark.envelopeTime2) {
                    sparkAlpha = -255/spark.envelopeTime2*(spark.age - spark.envelopeTime2);
                }
                else {
                    spark.dead = true;
                }   
                if ((spark.dead)||(spark.pos.x > displayWidth) || (spark.pos.x < 0) || (spark.pos.y > displayHeight) || (spark.pos.y < -topMargin)) {
                    sparkList.recycleParticle(spark);
                }
                sparkColor = (sparkAlpha << 24) | spark.color;
                presentAlpha = (sparkBitmapData.getPixel32(spark.pos.x, spark.pos.y) >> 24) & 0xFF;
                if (sparkAlpha > presentAlpha) {
                    sparkBitmapData.setPixel32(spark.pos.x, spark.pos.y, sparkColor);
                }
                spark = nextSpark;
            }
            sparkBitmapData.unlock();
            grayAmt = 4 + 26*sparkList.numOnStage/5000;
            if (grayAmt > 30) {
                grayAmt = 30;
            }
            sky.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,1,grayAmt,grayAmt,1.08*grayAmt,0);
        }

        function randomColor():uint {
            var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*colorList.length);
            return colorList[index];
        }
```

Comment: not enough info to help with this.. Is the animation a tween?

Comment: it's based on actionscript as mentioned. the script declares the x and y position of the object so there's no tweening happening on the frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will stop your animation:

```
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
```

Comment: I've done that but the problem is the animation is based on the actionscript and not a movieclip

Comment: well show us some code then and we might stand a chance to help you

Comment: for now I added a fader on the end instead of forcing stop the animation.